# Select value if it appears elsewhere in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql and I'm interested in rows where reciprocals appear in a different row in the table.

Imagine 2 columns, each with letters a through z.

Lets say row1 has a,b, row2 has a,c, and row 3 has c,a.  I am interested in the pair a,c because it appears both as c,a and a,c in different rows in the table.

Do I have to use a nested select? Or perhaps an exists clause?

Comment: You don't have to add tags to your titles, there's a tag system for that. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're after, a self-join:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table1 t2
 ON t1.col1 = t2.col2
 AND t1.col2 = t2.col1
```

Here is a SQL fiddle demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32034/1/0)

Comment: note that a row like `('a','a')` will match itself. The general pattern to avoid matching a row to itself would be an inequality predicate on an identifier column, eg. ` AND t1.id > t2.id`

Answer (score 0):

also use `SELECT REVERSE('abc')` see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse with above @spencer7593 said

```
`SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table1 t2
 ON t1.col1 = t2.col2
 AND t1.col2 = t2.col1`
```

Comment: I am trying a self join, and it seems increadibly slow.  Cant I do a select if select reverse exists, or something of that nature?